# How to collapse HTML whitespace?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sanitization

*Moderators: Before you vote to close this question, please ask yourself: "Am I voting to close this because someone else did before, or because it genuinely isn't a valid question?"*

I'm using [Sanitize](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/) to process user-generated content. It's a variant of the "relaxed" option and sometimes end up with content like `<div><span><br/></span>&nbsp;<span><br/></span> </div>` after sanitisation, which will produce unnecessary whitespace.

How can content like this be generically transformed to be just a single line-break if there's any linebreaks, or just to nothing if there's only empty tags?

The input content could be anything as it's user-generated. What comes out after sanitizing is mostly clean, sanitized, HTML but sometimes containing useless whitespace, which causes unnecessary blank lines that should be compressed.

Comment: It could be anything, it's user-generated. What comes out is mostly sanitized HTML but sometimes containing useless whitespace, which causes unnecessary blank lines, that should be compressed.

Comment: Why the close votes? This seems like a good question to me. How can you strip whitespace in an HTML-aware way?

Comment: Because a lot of people vote to close when someone else already voted to close. #Groupthink

Answer (score 1):

You could take the simplest route and do a `gsub` replacement of patterns you know produce unnecessary white space. The output could really be anything depending on what WYSIWYG editor you are utilizing. There may not be a pre-boxed solution. In the end you'll just have to do something like this:

i.e., `my_string.gsub /(<div><span><br\/><\/span>&nbsp;<span><br\/><\/span>( )+<\/div>)+/, ''`

Use [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/) to test out your regex quickly.

Then again perhaps there's an HTML > plain text, plain text > HTML converter out there. Depending on the complexity of your allowed HTML elements/attributes, you could do this:

1) Convert the HTML input to plain text formatting
2) `gsub`/strip the input
3) Convert back to the HTML formatting

Keep in mind that if you allow HTML attributes, they might be lost in the conversion...this requires testing.